# NSDate to GMTDate to JSON format

Tags: objective-c, ios, nsdate, nstimeinterval, nstimezone

I want to convert my Local date ([NSDate date]) to GMT to create a JSON string (/Date(1324435876019-0000)/).

My code works fine when i set my clock to EST time zone when i change my timezone to PST my code still acts as EST. Can you please tell me what is the problem is following code?

```
        NSDate *localDate = [NSDate date];
    NSTimeInterval timeZoneOffset = [[NSTimeZone systemTimeZone] secondsFromGMT]; // You could also use the systemTimeZone method
    NSTimeInterval gmtTimeInterval = [localDate timeIntervalSinceReferenceDate] - timeZoneOffset;
    NSDate *gmtDate = [NSDate dateWithTimeIntervalSinceReferenceDate:gmtTimeInterval];
    NSString *time = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"/Date(%@-0000)/", [NSNumber numberWithLongLong:[gmtDate timeIntervalSince1970] * 1000]];
```

Comment: Current time is 2011-12-20 05:15:00 +0000 But if i NSLog gmtDate i am getting out put as 1) ESt tim zone: 2011-12-21 03:15:00 +0000 2) PSTtime zone :2011-12-21 06:15:00 +0000. Which is wrong. I think i am not getting right GMT date. What you think ?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can get the epoch `GMT` time by simply calling `timeIntervalSince1970`.

```
NSString *time = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"/Date(%lld-0000)/", 
                     (long long)([[NSDate date] timeIntervalSince1970] * 1000)];
```

Comment: First thing timeIntervalSince1970 will give you in second and we need to pass millisecond for JSON. I implemented this logic first but i was not able to find right answer.

Comment: Updated answer. You do not need to do any timezone calculations to get the GMT time, that one liner is all you need.

Comment: @AmitVyawahare: timeIntervalSince1970 uses seconds as its units but returns an NSTimeInterval, which is a double, with quite a bit of fractional precision. So Joe's solution is correct and should give you millisecond resolution.

Answer (score 0):

@joe and @tommy you are right. Even i implemneted the same way as you mentioned. Problem was in server database. I found a hack. I just need to add 18000 (5 hr) second to the current local date and i am good. So code is

```
        NSDate *localDate = [NSDate date];
    NSTimeInterval gmtTimeInterval = [localDate timeIntervalSinceReferenceDate] + 18000;
    NSDate *gmtDate = [NSDate dateWithTimeIntervalSinceReferenceDate:gmtTimeInterval];

    NSString *time = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"/Date(%@-0000)/", [NSNumber numberWithLongLong:[gmtDate timeIntervalSince1970] * 1000]];
```

Comment: That is not really a good solution (as you know since you used the word hack), do not forget that there is `EST` and `EDT`. Your server just needs to display the time back in the correct timezone, maybe the  solution is to change the "-0000" to "-0500"(EST)/"-0400"(EDT) instead.

Comment: You are right hack is not good but till the point server is not fixed i have to use same crapy code. Thank you, --AV